# Sonar: Create new rule for Android Lint

Tags: java, android, xpath, sonarqube, lint

I am using **SonarQube 5.1** in order to collect all **Java** and **Lint** errors for **Android** apps.

Almost every important issue is already caught by Sonar using Lint plugin, but I have found at least one issue not included:

```
<issue
    id="GradleOverrides"
    severity="Warning"
    message="This `minSdkVersion` value (`14`) is not used; it is always overridden by the value specified in the Gradle build script (`15`)"
    category="Correctness"
    priority="4"
    summary="Value overridden by Gradle build script"
    explanation="The value of (for example) `minSdkVersion` is only used if it is not specified in the `build.gradle` build scripts. When specified in the Gradle build scripts, the manifest value is ignored and can be misleading, so should be removed to avoid ambiguity."
    errorLine1="    &lt;uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion=&quot;14&quot; />"
    errorLine2="              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~">
    <location
        file="C:\Code\Android\TestApp\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml"
        line="5"
        column="15"/>
</issue>
```

This issue is related to `AndroidManifest.xml` (legacy way to set Android `minSdkVersion` attribute) and `build.gradle` (current way to set `minSdkVersion` element).

I have read the [documentation about creating new rules in Sonar](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extending+Coding+Rules), but I am 
still confused. I have downloaded the [SSLR for XML](http://repository.codehaus.org/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/xml/sslr-xml-toolkit/1.2/) and executed it to find the XPath string.

My XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.juanacaja.testapp" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

...and the XPath to look for `minSdkVersion` element is:

```
//manifest/uses-sdk/@android:minSdkVersion
```

I am not sure what I must do now. Moreover, the SonarQube 5.1 web interface has changed and I don't see how to add the XPath string to the new rule.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: By the way, old links to SonarQube documentation are currently broken, like this one: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules. Someone at SonarSource could fix it?

Comment: Yep, this is an ongoing process due to the shutdown of CodeHaus - new URL is http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Extending+Coding+Rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidentally I have found how to do this. Steps:

1. Log in as *administrator* or other user with sufficient rights.
2. [Look for XPath rule](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#q=xpath) for the language, XML in this case.
3. Press **Create** button near "Custom Rules" text and fill form.

Do not forget to activate this custom rule in your profile.

**PS**: IMHO, the underlying problem is that documentation is not updated, and the vast majority of URLs are currently broken, due [CodeHaus termination](https://www.codehaus.org/termination/). Until old broken links will be corrected, it would be great if automatic redirection be performed.

Comment: where do i need to login as admin ? on sonar dashboard ??

Comment: Yo need to "login" at upper-right corner, next to "search icon". By default, login is "admin" | "admin".

Comment: How to incorporate this new rule which is created under Manual Rule repository in android-sonar-master ?

Comment: Try to follow steps above and explain the problem you encountered.